# PC won't work if new SSD is inserted

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, power-supply, sata

[Please pardon my English. I might not know the proper names of some HW things in English, sorry]

Today I got a new SSD! Yay! Twice as big as my old, 120gb SSD...

Well I wish I had my 240gb of space right away, but... I have a problem.

When I plug it in, my computer won't boot... at all. Usually, I am my friend's tech support. But since I can't afford to tinker with hardware, it's a world unknown to me.

Basic info:

- Drive is for SATA3 [brand new] (Kingston Now A400, 2,5" - 240GB)
- Data cable is labeled SATA III [brand new]
- Power cable is labeled S-ATA 3 (that's the same thing... right? I'm
  not sure at this point) [found in my box in which MB came in]
- I have 620w power supply. I heard it might be power problem, but I don't think so. Still worth mentioning, though. (I have GTX 960 and Intel I5 3.3 ghz processor)

Every single time I plug the drive in, the pc will not turn on at all. Not even to BIOS. I have to unplug the drive and turn off the power supply with a switch, wait a few minutes and then I can turn on the computer and boot to Windows with both of my old drives showing. (new drive is fully unplugged)

first I tried to plug the new data cable into the port on the other edge of the MB. Then I unplugged the functioning drive and plugged in the new drive (I did not unplug the power cable because I have no idea what cable plugged into power supply it is) - I did not plug the old drive into the MB.

It did not work. I tried a different connection on my power supply (I still have 2 SATA marked "holes" left), but it did not work.

I have no idea what to do right now. I'm just going to assume I'm ignorant and I overlooked something major. Please, would you be so kind and help me?

Comment: Jaroslav, I made some minor grammar corrections. BTW, to "brick" something means, to me, to *permanently* destroy a device (with the idea that it can only function as a building brick or as a boat anchor).

Comment: Alright. I remember seeing that Anthem (I think) that "bricked" PS4 but it was reversible so that's where I heard it. But thank you ^,^

Comment: It could be a DoA SSD? Is it possible to try the SSD on another PC?

Comment: I am not sure what DoA SSD is. And I own only one PC.

Comment: @JaroslavNejedlý, **DoA** means **D**ead **o**n **A**rrival; i.e. the SSD was non-functional when it arrived with you =)

Comment: May be one possibility is that there's a short somewhere on the electronic circuitry on the SSD. As a result PSU is getting into Short circuit protection and not starting.

Comment: As it sounds like the system won't even power on, I would suggest checking for short circuit issues in the power connector (e.g: metal pins touching). If that looks fine, then I'd suggest that the SSD is faulty. Please also confirm if the PC will boot with the new SSD connected via SATA but with power disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (TL;DR): Used a different power cable

The story: I brought it into my school and sked the teacher if I could test the drive in one of school machines. He agreed and we tested the drive using his cables. Everything worked. Then we used my data cable and it also worked. Then he told me that the power cablem ight be the issue because some PSU has some pins swapped and that renders them incompatible with other PSUs. Well I was digging in my boxes until I found a cable that looked the same as all of the other cables in my system and that worked.

I did not know that these cables work that way so I just assumed if it fits it's good enough lol. I changed PSU to a different one after a year or so, so I had the cables mixed up and when I tried a different cable, it was still from the old PSU.

I'd like to thank all of those people who tried to help me. I really appreciate that.